# How to add tooltip in flexigrid?

Tags: jquery, flexigrid

I am  new to flexigrid but  there isnt much documentation or examples on  How can a tooltip  and multiline tooltip be added to each cell in  flexigrid tables and to the table headers.

Are there any example and samples for flexigrid tooltip?

THanks

about flexigrid http://flexigrid.info/

Comment: you need to handle the tr and tds how a tooltip handles ..best is to give a try and then ask if u face any problem ...have a look at this link http://jquerytools.org/demos/tooltip/table.html

Comment: @swapnesh - your link seems to be broken..

Comment: its opening correctly at myend

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get tool tips working using the following code.

```
function loadToolTips(){
$('#Employees tr').each( function(){

            var tooltip = 'Employee Code : '
            tooltip = tooltip + $('[abbr="EmployeeCode"]',this).text();
            tooltip = tooltip + '<br />';

            tooltip = tooltip + 'Name: ' 
            tooltip = tooltip + $('[abbr="Name"]',this).text();
            tooltip = tooltip + '<br />';

            tooltip = tooltip + 'Department: ' 
            tooltip = tooltip + $('[abbr="Department"]',this).text();
            tooltip = tooltip + '<br />';

            tooltip = tooltip + 'Section: ' 
            tooltip = tooltip + $('[abbr="Section"]',this).text();

            $("td", this).each(function() {
                var $TableCell = $(this);
                $TableCell.attr("title", tooltip);
                $TableCell.addClass("tooltip");
            });
        });
$('.tooltip').tooltipster();
```

}

I first iterate through all of the rows in the grid and build up the tool tip by getting the values from each cell in the row by using the abbr's.

for each cell within the row I then add the title attribute with the tool tip value.

I also add a class tool tip but this is only because I am using tooltipster.

I call the loadToolTips function when the onSuccess method is called.

```
preProcess: somefunction,
onSuccess: loadToolTips
```